# Handler not running 1000 times in 1 second

Tags: java, android, handler, runnable, android-handler

I have a task in which i want to update something every millisecond(some kind of calculations). Now here is what i am doing giving 1 millisecond delay.-

```
 int countertest =0;

 myRunnable = new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        countertest++;
                        System.out.println("----counter----->"+countertest);
                        myHandler.postDelayed(myRunnable, 1); //runs every 1 millisecond
                    }
                };
```

I start `myHandler` on click of a button and stop it (`removeCallbacksAndMessages(null)`) exactly after 1 second. Now `myHandler` was supposed to run it 1000 times in one second. But it runs sometimes 110 times, sometimes 119 sometimes...some random numbers. Don't know why its not running exactly 1000 times in 1 second. Can anyone elaborate on it please.

What should I do now to execute something exactly 1000 times in 1 second ? Let's say for sake of just example if i want to show text from 0000 to 1000 in one second or print 0-1000 exactly in 1 second, neither more than 1 second nor less. **Downvoters** pls. comment below so that i can know where i am wrong. Thanks.

Device used for above test - Samsung S9.

Comment: if you really need to execute something that often it might be best to use a loop and just check if enough time passed using `System.nanotime` - this still might not be exact 1000 as this still depends on system, but in most cases it should run fine. Also your code isn't executing this every 1 millisecond, but 1 millisecond + time needed to execute it.

Comment: I don't think that incrementing integer is taking 100s milliseconds @GotoFinal

Comment: 10ms* Ofc it does not, but just saying that it isn't precise anyway, and incrementing integer is only one of 3 operations - creating new task to delay might take a bit - but also probably less than 1ms. So just results around 900 would be possible too.

Comment: yeah but myHandler makes that runnable runs only around 100-120 times. I am using `Samsung S9` ,its having good RAM.

Comment: You got already answers why, I just given you other idea if you really need something like that - to create a loop. But real questions seems to be: why you need to execute something that often on a phone?

Comment: That's my requirement for something. Can't go in so much detail here. That's why i stated an example.

Answer (score 3):

As stated [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis()), there is no guarantee for milliseconds accuracy in "your "system at all:

> Returns the current time in milliseconds. Note that while the unit of
>   time of the return value is a millisecond, the granularity of the
>   value depends on the underlying operating system and may be larger.
>   For example, many operating systems measure time in units of tens of
>   milliseconds.

Comment: Then what would be the right way of getting something executed exactly 1000 times in exact 1 second ?

Comment: @karanatwal.github.io, that could be very hard to do, maybe impossible, for a program running on a typical desktop, server, or mobile device operating system. If you need precision timing, then chances are, you need your code to run on a _[real-time operating system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_operating_system)_, or maybe even on _[bare metal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bare_machine)_.

Answer (score 1):

Delays cannot respects exactly what we set. For example the "Thread.sleep(1)" could take more than 10ms to be executed. Same things for "postDelayed()" method. The resolution is CPU and current_load depending and all the Docs/Guides warns about this "not absolute exact" time in these cases.